# How to load data from database for 1st time and use same data till refresh button is clicked in a web app

Tags: spring, mybatis, sapui5

Scenario.
My application has 2 tabs :
1 tab shows overview of the some details which when clicked or selected does a DB call and displays data.
2nd tab shows detailed data from 1st tab's data for which it too does a db call for which query is different.
There is auto update which updates new data in every 5 minutes.
For eg: Its an inventory app. I open 1 tab I see 5 Tvs but when I navigate to 2nd tab I see 10 Tvs as when I go to second tab it again makes a DB call and gets new data.

How is it possible to achieve data consistancy throughout i.e. if auto update is ON I should have same data in all tabs for 5 minutes after which new data comes for next 5 mins but if auto update is off I want to show same data through the single session.

I am using MyBatis,Spring and OpenUi5.

Comment: Have a look to [cache](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#cache).

Comment: Thanks! But there is a doubt. while sometimes I would get data from cache but sometimes I want to connect from db so how to achieve that.

Comment: There is a cache adapter for mybatis: http://www.mybatis.org/ehcache-cache/. You have an example of implementation here: https://dzone.com/articles/caching-over-mybatis-widelly

Comment: Can I change the value of flushInterval dynamically and also can I disable flushing at all as I want data to remain same throughout the session.